# How to implement custom ostringstream-like formatting states?

Tags: c++, c++11, formatting, ostream

**PROBLEM**

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
enum eOutputMode
{
  DECIMAL,
  BILLS_AND_COINS
};

class BankAccount
{
  ssize_t         m_dollars;
  unsigned short  m_pennies;

public:
  friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& os, BankAccount const& rhs )
  {
    // switch on eOutputMode : output in DECIMAL or in BILLS_AND_COINS
    return os;
  }
};
```

**QUESTION**

*How can I modify the code above so that I can call it like this?*

```
BankAccount  ba;
os << eOutputMode::DECIMAL << ba << "\n";
os << eOutputMode::BILLS_AND_COINS << ba << "\n";
```

*In other words, how and where should I capture the output states?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an output manipulator and capture the states in [ios_base::iword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iword) (that page has an example of a custom stateful manipulator)